# batch script to handle files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a config file, The file is like
mach.conf

```
Machine_IP = <IP Address>
Machine_Name = <Machine name>
User_Name = <UID>
ERRORCODE = 8000
..
```

Likewise. I am new to windows batch script, though I had read on internet about batch scripting and able to understand & write simple batch scripts. But no where I find handling files using batch script, like I want to read the config file if I see ERRORCODE = 8000
do a change and replace 8000 with 8001.

How to do this using batch scripting. Please provide me links or some hints.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I've added a bit of code that may not be necessary, but allows the program to manipulate unquoted **<**'s and **>**'s. All it does is pre-pend a **^** to them, so **<** becomes **^<** and **>** becomes **^>**.

```
@echo off
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 if exist config.tmp del config.tmp
 for /f "tokens=1* delims== " %%x in (config.cnf) do call :processFile "%%x" "%%y"
 move config.tmp config.cnf > nul
 echo File Updated
 endlocal
goto :eof

:processFile
 set "Var=%~1"
 set "Val=%~2"

 :: Add Escape Code to the greater-than and less-than symbols so they don't
 :: act as pipes and create errors.
 set "Var=%Var:<=^<%"
 set "Var=%Var:>=^>%"
 set "Val=%Val:<=^<%"
 set "Val=%Val:>=^>%"

 if "%Var%"=="ERRORCODE" set /a Val=%Val% + 1

 echo %Var% = %Val%>> config.tmp
```

Comment: @jeb For several reasons. 1) `<>` is included in the pseudo data provided by the OP, though I doubt it would be in the actual data. 2) You should be able to extrapolate how to do it yourself from my examples. 3) To add them would have been more work. 4) I doubt that any of these characters will be in an actual configuration file, so it would be an unnecessary complication and distraction from the actual question asked. As it is the examples I gave make up nearly 1/3 of the code already and each additional character requires two more lines of code.